# Common work at the begining of matrix build

Tags: jenkins

I have a project where the build process first needs to generate some platform independent data using the host tools and then packages for individual platforms are built.

I've been building them sequentially, but I want to change it to multi-configuration build to spread the load and also because some of the tools can only be installed on specific architectures.

Is there any way to do some work on in the driver job before starting the individual configurations? Or perhaps using the touchstone configuration (I'd need to make the artefacts available to the other configurations)?

Of course I can create pipeline with parametrized trigger plugin and copy artefacts plugin. But I'll have multiple jobs with similar setup, so I would prefer avoiding the job combinatorial explosion if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be somewhat possible with the [Environment Script Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin). The fact it's output is captured to environment variables makes it a bit complicated to debug.